# Bootstrap Custom Table Widths

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

My question is a little bit different than what is already out there.
I'm trying to create a table which has a certain width. The table has 3 columns. I want the first two columns to have an automatic width, and the third column to fill the remaining space.

Here's what I have so far, it's not quite working. The columns all have equal width. I have tried to set `width: auto !important` on the whole table, but then the third column is not filling the remaining space.

```
.message-timestamp {
    width: auto !important;
}
.message-nick {
      width: auto !important;
}

<table class="table table-hover" style="float:left; width:74%">
  <tr>
    <td class="message-timestamp">2015-02-03 11:15:16</td>
    <td class="message-nick">ResidentBiscuit</td>
    <td class="message-text">This is just a message</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="message-timestamp">2015-02-03 11:16:35</td>
    <td class="message-nick">SomeNick</td>
    <td class="message-text">I'm replying to ResidentBiscuit</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And here's the [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/454XQq9IH0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully I understood what you wanted here.  Try this:

```
.message-timestamp {
    width: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.message-nick {
    width: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.message-text {
    width: 100%;
}
```

This will give you auto-fit for the first two columns (and I added white-space to prevent the text from wrapping) and the third fills the row up.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code by giving fixed width to first two columns and remove table width auto from css.

```
<table class="table table-hover" style="float:left; width:100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="message-timestamp" style="width:10%">2015-02-03 11:15:16</td>
<td class="message-nick" style="width:10%">ResidentBiscuit</td>
<td class="message-text">This is just a message</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="message-timestamp">2015-02-03 11:16:35</td>
<td class="message-nick">SomeNick</td>
<td class="message-text">I'm replying to ResidentBiscuit</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Hope this helps